# jQuery/Javascript event not triggering on <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue with event triggering on a `<a>` tag. The alert doesn't show when it is clicked.

```
$('.thb-audio-wrapper #fap-play-pause').on("click",function(){ alert('hello'); });
```

Comment: Your valid HTML ????

Comment: Do you put you js inside document ready?

Comment: Assuming you're using a plugin for that audio control, it's possible that it has already hooked to that element and is using `return false`, or `preventDefault()`. If that's the case you would need to hook to a parent element, check the `e.target` and hope that they haven't also use `stopPropagation()` in the plugin.

Comment: Yes, i added my event in document.ready as well

Comment: Rory McCrossan, can you please tell me how to use stopPropagation() and e.target. You can try this by adding your code in head section and tell how to do this. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't think that is a valid selector

Comment: @Mark: it's a perfectly valid selector, though it might not match an element within the HTML the OP's created.

Comment: @DavidThomas Fair. I guess I meant it is an unusual selector since, in theory, element Id's should be unique to a page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
$('.thb-audio-wrapper').on("click", '#fap-play-pause' ,function(){ alert('hello'); });
```

Comment: where is the stop event propagation?